# MongoDB schema suggestion re: embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a collection of people. Each person may have many books. Each book has a date when it was withdrawn.

This is my first time using Mongo coming from traditional SQL. My first inclination was to make each book withdrawn a subdocument. However, this appears to make ordering of subdocuments a pain.

Something like this for example:

```
Schemas.Person = new SimpleSchema({
  "name": {
    type: String
  },
  "withdrawals.$": {
    type: Object
  },
  "withdrawals.$.withdrawalDate": {
    type: Date
  },
  "withdrawals.$.bookName": {
    type: String
  }
});
```

For example, if I wanted to get a list of people that have withdrawn a book ordered by when they withdrew it, I think with Mongo that gets really complicated.

Should I be using references and split the withdrawls from the Person collection?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

[Overembedding is the root of all evil.](http://blog.mahlberg.io/blog/2015/11/05/data-modelling-for-mongodb/)

There is a size limit on BSON documents of 16MB as of the time of this writing (and the foreseeable future). If you really want to make it possible for a Person to have unlimited books, you can not embed the books. The same applies for the number of withdrawals.

What we have here is a well known pattern, relations with attributes, meaning that the relations themselves are qualified by additional attributes.

So what you want to have here is a `persons` collection, with the all the data of the persons, a books collection with all the data of the books, and a withdrawal collection to document who borrowed which book on which date (and may be even returned it).

This is due to the fact that your use cases basically look like this:

1. For a *given* book, is it available? (= No open withdrawal)
2. For a *given* withdrawal, who borrowed the book?
3. For a *given* user and a *given* book and a *given* date, document the withdrawal.
4. For a *given* user and a *given* book and a *given* date, document the return.

## The collections

So a stub of your `person` collection looks like

```
{
    _id: new ObjectId()
   username: "foo",
   …
}
```

Your books collection looks similar:

```
{
    _id: "someISBN"
    title: "Foobar and Barbaz explore the Mongoverse"
    …
}
```

A withdrawal document looks like this:

```
{
    _id: new ObjectId(),
    userId: someUserObjectId,
    bookId: someBookId,
    withdrawalDate: new ISODate(),
    // returnDate can be omitted, too
    // since non-existing values evaluate to null
    returnDate: null
}
```

## Availability check

Now, let's say somebody found a book he or she wants to withdraw, you find out wether it is available by issuing

```
> db.withdrawals.find({bookId:someBookId,returnDate:null})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56bc6c8188d0e8d074b11a8d"), "userId" : ObjectId("56bc6bd888d0e8d074b11a8a"), "bookId" : "1234567890", "withdrawalDate" : ISODate("2016-02-11T11:12:01.325Z") }
```

If this query finds something, the book was borrowed and not returned, yet. If no document was returned, you'd know that the book should be available.

*Note*: with the document returned, you now can find out who borrowed the book by querying the `persons` collection, since we have the userId:

```
> db.persons.find({_id:ObjectId("56bc6bd888d0e8d074b11a8a")})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56bc6bd888d0e8d074b11a8a"), "username" : "mwm" }
```

## Withdrawals and returns

When user "mwm" borrowed the book, it was documented in the easiest way:

```
  db.withdrawals.insert({
     userId:ObjectId("56bc6bd888d0e8d074b11a8a"),
     bookId:"0987654321",
     withdrawalDate:new ISODate("2016-01-01T12:00:00Z")
  })
```

Now when the (known) book is returned by a (known)user, documenting it is extremely easy:

```
db.withdrawals.update(
{
    "userId":ObjectId("56bc6bd888d0e8d074b11a8a"),
    "bookId":"0987654321"
},{
    $set:{ returnDate: newISODate() }
})
```

Comment: Thank you markus for such a thorough answer. I will certainly try this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, each document in your `Person` collection looks like this -

```
{
  name: String,
  withdrawals: [
    {
      bookName: String,
      withdrawalDate: Date
    },
    {
      bookName: String,
      withdrawalDate: Date
    }
    .
    .
    .
  ]
}
```

If this is the case, I believe you can use the following query to get the list of all people who have borrowed a particular book (*book1 in this example*) ordered by ascending order of date of withdrawal.

```
Person.find({ "withdrawals.bookName": "book1" }, {
  sort: { "withdrawals.withdrawalDate": 1 }
});
```

Comment: Hi umesh

Thank you for your reply. The result I'm looking for would be something like:

    {"_id": ObjectId("whatever"), "name": "Bob", "withdrawl": [{ "name": "book1", THIS BIT ORDERED "withdrawlDate": ISODate(oldest)}

So the embedded documents themselves are sorted irrelevant to the sort of the primary document if that makes sense?

Comment: Yes, the order of embedded documents is irrelevant to the primary sort order. The above query sorts the Person documents in ascending order of date of withdrawal for a particular book name. If this is not the query that you were looking for, could you please elaborate more on what you're trying to achieve here?